# Kotlin "warning: some JAR files in the classpath have the Kotlin Runtime library bundled into them"

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

For some reason I receive this warning when I start my application:

> warning: some JAR files in the classpath have the Kotlin Runtime
>   library bundled into them. This may cause difficult to debug problems
>   if there's a different version of the Kotlin Runtime library in the
>   classpath. Consider removing these libraries from the classpath or use
>   '-Xskip-runtime-version-check' to suppress this warning warning:
>   library has Kotlin runtime bundled into it

I use Gradle to build my application using the `kotlin-script-util` dependency, which I noticed has a dependency on `kotlin-script-runtime` which I figured was the problem. I thus excluded that dependency in Gradle like so:

```
compile(group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-script-util', version: kotlin_version) {
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-script-runtime'
}
```

Unfortunately no dice. Does anybody know how to get rid of this warning? `-Xskip-runtime-version-check` is not an option for my use case.

Comment: Run `gradlew dependencies` to see where the dependency comes from.

Comment: @KirillRakhman Which dependency in particular are you looking for?

Comment: Is this the whole output? The second warning should have the path of the problematic library included

Comment: @AlexanderUdalov that is all that is printing in the console.

Comment: @AlexanderUdalov Yes, it's the entire output. Something I forgot to mention is that we use 1.1 beta 2 (version 38)

Comment: In that case it may be a bug, please report an issue at http://kotl.in/issue. Thanks!